# How to draw const plot on polar axis?

Tags: pgfplots, plot, polarplot

I want to draw planisphere with constellation borders from file with points. But points are connected by line, not arcs.

```
\begin{polaraxis}
    \addplot+[mark=none,very thin,blue,solid,const plot] table[x=r,y=d,col sep=semicolon]{Ari.csv};
\end{polaraxis}
```

File looks like (Orion):

```
    % Ari
    r d
    030.0000   9.9167
    025.0000   9.9167
    025.0000  25.0000
    028.7500  25.0000
    028.7500  27.2500
    036.2500  27.2500
    036.2500  30.6667
    040.7500  30.6667
    050.5000  30.6667
    050.5000  19.0000
    049.2500  19.0000
    049.2500   9.9167
    030.0000   9.9167
```

And `const plot` option doesn't work correctly (blue field)
[image: example]

I want to draw like this (rounded borders)

[image]

How to draw lines (between points) along the grid of polar plot? Sorry my english:)

Comment: A somewhat impractical workaround would be to interpolate the data file to get more datapoints, and use a standard plot. With more datapoints you get a better approximation of a curve.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome! Technically the `const plot` handler does what it is supposed to do. Are you perhaps looking for a `smooth cycle` plot handler?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{filecontents}{Ari.csv}
    r d
    030.0000   9.9167
    025.0000   9.9167
    025.0000  25.0000
    028.7500  25.0000
    028.7500  27.2500
    036.2500  27.2500
    036.2500  30.6667
    040.7500  30.6667
    050.5000  30.6667
    050.5000  19.0000
    049.2500  19.0000
    049.2500   9.9167
    030.0000   9.9167
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}
    \addplot+[mark=none,very thin,blue,solid,smooth cycle,tension=0.2] 
    table[x=r,y=d,col sep=space]{Ari.csv};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, it is actually not too difficult to write your own plot handler, I did a simple one just yesterday [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/537884/194703). It just turns out that the documentation is not as good as it might be.