# Logarithmic Y axis + Colors + Arrow Heads in pgfplots polar charts

Tags: pgfplots, color, arrows, polar

I am trying to merge the excellent solution for [using logarithmic Y axis in pgfplots polar charts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537868/logarithmic-y-axis-in-pgfplots-polar-charts) with the excellent solution for [adding colors and arrow heads decorations to pgfplots polar chart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537853/how-to-add-colors-and-arrow-heads-decorations-to-pgfplots-polar-chart). Each of the solutions works great separately (see pictures in these links).

Unfortunately an attempt to combine them into one working example fails:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}[>=stealth,
        ymin=0, ymax=32,
        %ytick=\empty, axis y line=none, 
        point meta ={rawy},
        y coord trafo/.code =\pgfmathparse{log10(#1)},
        y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{10^#1},
        xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,
        every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
        visualization depends on={x\as\myx},
        visualization depends on={y\as\myy},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.append code={
        \pgftransformreset
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{(abs(sin(\myx))<0.01 ? "green" :
        (abs(cos(\myx))<0.01 ? "red" : "blue"))}
        %\typeout{\myx,\myy,\mycolor}
        \draw[->,color=\mycolor] (axis cs:0,0) -- 
        (axis cs:\myx,\myy) node[anchor=\myx-180]{\pgfmathprintnumber{\myy}\%};
        },
    ]
    \addplot+ [scatter,draw=none]
    coordinates {(0,21.6) (180,15.8)
    (90,11.4) (270,10.6)
    (30,5.3) (60,5.5) (120,4.0) (150,6.6) (210,5.2) (240,5.5) (300,3.4) (330,5.2)};
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should need to change `ymin=0` to e.g. `ymin=1` and have to hack one of the hacks. I hacked the one I am more familiar with.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}[>=stealth,
        ymin=1, ymax=36,%<- ymin=1 !
        %ytick=\empty, axis y line=none, 
        point meta ={rawy},
        y coord trafo/.code =\pgfmathparse{log10(#1)},
        y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{10^#1},
        xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,
        every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
        visualization depends on={x\as\myx},
        visualization depends on={y\as\myy},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.append code={
        \pgftransformreset
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{(abs(sin(\myx))<0.01 ? "green" :
        (abs(cos(\myx))<0.01 ? "red" : "blue"))}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\myanchoradd}{(abs(sin(\myx))<0.01 ?-90:0)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\myundoney}{pow(10,\myy)}
        %\typeout{\myx,\myy,\mycolor}
        \draw[->,color=\mycolor] (axis cs:0,1) -- 
        (axis cs:\myx,\myundoney) 
        node[anchor=\myx-180+\myanchoradd]{\pgfmathprintnumber{\myundoney}\%};
        },
    ]
    \addplot+ [scatter,draw=none]
    coordinates {(0,21.6) (180,15.8)
    (90,11.4) (270,10.6)
    (30,5.3) (60,5.5) (120,4.0) (150,6.6) (210,5.2) (240,5.5) (300,3.4) (330,5.2)};
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing. Many thanks for the quick answer.